# JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder. Path:

Tags: joomla2.5, yahoo

I'm receiving the following error `JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder. Path:` (with no path) when i create a menu item based off a K2 item.  Its a fresh install with only k2, Gantry Framework (with throws the same error on install), a template installed, and a few items created...

As you see from the tag its Joomla! version 2.5.14. `The PHP allow_url_fopen setting is disabled. This setting must be enabled for the updater to work.` 
(this is because i'm using Yahoo Small Business and from my understanding they don't allow customization of php settings and i'll never use them again after my year is up).

I've seen the issues on temp and logs and they are both `./logs` or `./tmp`

The template also looks pretty messed up but works fine on another site i have.

[image]

Other than that its all pretty new. Anyone have a work around or fixes for what i'd doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to a host that is set up to run Joomla. All of your errors are server configuration related.

Comment: I'd love to but i think he's committed to yahoo small business for a year.

Comment: Yahoo hosting is like $5 a month. You're going to spend MANY hours trying to make it work and it will never be right. It's worth losing $60 to not have to mess around with crappy hosting. He's committed to paying them the fee, not keeping the website there. It's going to cost a lot more in the long run if you leave the site there.

Comment: Thanks, for his beliefs he wishes to not go to goDaddy, and i don't want to cost him more money. So in the end i am gonna go with their built in word press installer.

Comment: Up to you, but there are reputable hosting solutions that don't cost a lot of money. Rochen Host offers a small business account for $8.95 per month and everything will work.